# Alternative to XML PATH

Tags: sql, t-sql

This inserts into 3 tables really quickly. My `SELECT` at the bottom appears to take an age, I assumed it would be fairly quick but is not. Is the XML path the right way to go?

```
DECLARE @TEAMMEMBER TABLE
        (CAREPROVIDEROID BIGINT, Team VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @MAINSPECIALTY TABLE
        (CAREPROVIDEROID BIGINT, MainSpecialty VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @TREATSPECIALTY TABLE
        (CAREPROVIDEROID BIGINT, TreatSpecialty VARCHAR(MAX))


INSERT INTO @TEAMMEMBER 
    SELECT 
    TEAMMEM.CAREPROVIDEROID as CAREPROVIDEROID,
    CAST(REPLACE(TEAM.NAME,'&','AND')+'('+TEAM.IDENTIFIER+')' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as Team
    FROM LZO_TEAMMEMBER TEAMMEM
    INNER JOIN LZO_TEAM TEAM
    ON TEAM.OID = TEAMMEM.TEAMOID
    AND TEAM.STATUS = 'A'
    --ORDER BY TEAMMEM.CAREPROVIDEROID


INSERT INTO @MAINSPECIALTY
    SELECT USERRP.USERSOID as USERSOIDMAINSPECIALTY,
    CAST(s.NAME +'('+s.MAINIDENTIFIER+')' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as MainSpec
    FROM LZO_USERROLEPROFILE USERRP

    INNER JOIN LZO_ROLEPROFILEENTERPRISEOBJECT RPEO
    ON USERRP.ROLEPROFILEOID = RPEO.ROLEPROFILEOID
    AND 'SPECIALTY' = RPEO.IDENTIFYINGTYPE 
    AND RPEO.STATUS = 'A'
    INNER JOIN LZO_Specialty s
    ON s.OID = RPEO.IdentifyingOID and s.SPETYCode = 'CC_CPSPE' --Specialty
    AND RPEO.STATUS = 'A'
    WHERE 1=1
    AND USERRP.STATUS='A'
    --ORDER BY USERRP.USERSOID

INSERT INTO @TREATSPECIALTY
    SELECT
    USERRP.USERSOID as USERSOIDTREATSPECIALTY,
    CAST(s.NAME +'('+s.MAINIDENTIFIER+')' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) as TreatSpec
    FROM LZO_USERROLEPROFILE USERRP
    INNER JOIN LZO_ROLEPROFILEENTERPRISEOBJECT RPEO
    ON USERRP.ROLEPROFILEOID = RPEO.ROLEPROFILEOID
    AND 'SPECIALTY' = RPEO.IDENTIFYINGTYPE 
    AND RPEO.STATUS = 'A'
    INNER JOIN LZO_Specialty s
    ON s.OID = RPEO.IdentifyingOID and s.SPETYCode = 'CC_TRTFN' --Treatment Function
    AND RPEO.STATUS = 'A'
    WHERE 1=1
    AND USERRP.STATUS='A'
    --ORDER BY USERRP.USERSOID




Select OID, 
       (SELECT sub.Team + ', ' AS [data()] 
            from @TEAMMEMBER as sub
            Where sub.CAREPROVIDEROID = LZO_USERS.OID
            Order by sub.Team asc
                  FOR XML PATH('')                
        ) as [Teams]

FROM LZO_USERS WHERE STATUS = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `ORDER BY` worked wonders and slightly altering the code:

```
,SUBSTRING(STUFF((SELECT ', '+TEAM FROM @TEAMMEMBER WHERE E.OID = CAREPROVIDEROID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),2,4000) AS TEAMS
```